# How to access broadcast variable from a udf and broadcast variable is defined in another class where this udf is being called

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**How to access the broadcast variable from a UDF and broadcast variable is defined in another class where this UDF is being called**.

```
    /* this udf is in different file */
    package com.abc
     public class JavaClass{
        public static UserDefinedFunction getvalue = udf((String param) -> {

        return "String value";
        }, DataTypes.StringType);

    }    
**/* below code is in different file */** 
    package com.xyz;
    import com.abc.JavaClass;
     public class AnotherClassToCallUDF{
        pubic static void main(String args[]) {
    Dataset<Row> abc = .......;

    abc.withColoumn("new-col",JavaClass.getvalue.apply("passing some value"));
    }

    }       

    **/* in the above code , how to pass broadcast variable while calling udf...since udf accepts only col typ`enter code here`e and lit type ..it does not accept anything else..then how to access broadcast variable which is defined in main class and accessing in another class..       
*/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

### 1. create UDF

```java
class MyUDF implements UDF1<Long, String> {
        private Map<Long, String> broadCastMap;
        public MyUDF(Broadcast<Map<Long, String>> broadCastMap) {
           this.broadCastMap = broadCastMap.value();
        }
        public String call(Long id) {
            return id +" -> " + broadCastMap.getOrDefault(id, "No mapping");
        }
    }
```

### 2. Use udf to pass the broadcast and use it

```java
Dataset<Row> inputDf = spark.range(1, 5).withColumn("col1", lit("a"));
        inputDf.show(false);
        inputDf.printSchema();
        /**
         * +---+----+
         * |id |col1|
         * +---+----+
         * |1  |a   |
         * |2  |a   |
         * |3  |a   |
         * |4  |a   |
         * +---+----+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- id: long (nullable = false)
         *  |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
         */

        // Create broadcast
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1L, "b");
        map.put(2L, "c");
        Broadcast<Map<Long, String>> broadCastMap = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).broadcast(map);

        UserDefinedFunction myUdf = udf(new MyUDF(broadCastMap), DataTypes.StringType);

        spark.sqlContext().udf().register("myUdf", myUdf);

        inputDf.withColumn("new_col", callUDF("myUdf",
                JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(Collections.singletonList(col("id"))).asScala()))
                .show();
        /**
         * +---+----+---------------+
         * | id|col1|        new_col|
         * +---+----+---------------+
         * |  1|   a|         1 -> b|
         * |  2|   a|         2 -> c|
         * |  3|   a|3 -> No mapping|
         * |  4|   a|4 -> No mapping|
         * +---+----+---------------+
         */
```

### 3. Without registering the UDF to `FunctionRegistry`

```java
 inputDf.withColumn("new_col", myUdf.apply(col("id")))
                .show();
        /**
         * +---+----+---------------+
         * | id|col1|        new_col|
         * +---+----+---------------+
         * |  1|   a|         1 -> b|
         * |  2|   a|         2 -> c|
         * |  3|   a|3 -> No mapping|
         * |  4|   a|4 -> No mapping|
         * +---+----+---------------+
         */
```

Comment: I am using the spark version 2.3.4 , where the udf are being called as below..                                                                                                                   






dataset.withColumn("colName",
     getValuefromUDF.getValue.apply(col("col1")));
so , here the argument of an udf is a type of col ? Would that take the broadcast type as an argument ?

Comment: `callUDF` is there since `spark-1.5`, since you don't want to register the udf use `step-3`. see my edited answer. Feel free to accept + upvote if it helps

Comment: In 3rd. point - you are calling a UDF without registering it that is fine. but in udf definition how to access the broadcast variable, if we try to access the broadcast variable in udf which is defined in some other class it will not compile,  because broadcast variable we have defined in driver class and UDF is defined in some other class. for example i have edited the question to show the code snippet...

Comment: @Devender Prakash is this worked ? I am having same issue , how to solve it ?